# How to get SID of a group once i get groups of a user in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am using DirectorySearcher to get groups of a User in ActiveDirectory.

My Question is how to get SID associated with each group once i get user groups using "memberOf"?

I am working in .NETFramework 2.0 Environment.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", sUserDomain));
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user) (cn= {0}))", ui.DisplayName.ToString());
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
SearchResult searchresult = mySearcher.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do it in one single LDAP search because `memberOf` returns a distinguish name.  You have to do another bind to get the `objectSid` attribute from the group object.  Here is the code.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", sUserDomain));
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user) (cn= {0}))", ui.DisplayName.ToString());
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
SearchResult searchresult = mySearcher.FindOne();

foreach (string dn in searchresult.Properties["memberOf"])
{
    DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", sUserDomain, dn));
    SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(group.Properties["objectSid"][0] as byte[], 0);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(sid.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The above code works to retrieve one group, but if a member is in multiple groups can you please guide me how to loop and get list of groups

Comment: @phanishm Updated my answer to get the list of groups.  I also fixed the binding to use specified domain name

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
    // define context for current domain
    using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        // find  user 
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourNameHere");

        if (user != null)
        {
            // get groups the user is a member of
            var groups = current.GetGroups();

            // iterate over all those groups
            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                // fetch the SID for each group
                var sid = group.Sid;
            }
        }
    }
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Unfortunately, our product is developed in .NetFramework 2.0,is there a way to integrated this in .Net Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at his article:
[Retrieving user SID using DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher](http://philippsen.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/retrieving-user-sid-using-directoryentry-and-directorysearcher/)

This gives you a full working example for retrieving the SID.

Comment: Thanks, but i need sid of a group user belongs to.

Comment: It should work exactly the same way.  Just specify a filter for DirectorySearcher that finds the group you're interested.